# Как обновить переменную в переменной в Javascript+Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

```
        var a_params_idno = 0;

        var a_params = '\
                    <form id="appartment_params_'+a_params_idno+'">\
                    <something.......>\
                    </form>';

        for (var i=0; i<h_appf; i++){
            a_params_idno++;
            $("#appartment_layout").after(a_params);
        }
После этого я в HTML коде вижу что в конце id-шников у всех форм стоит appartment_params_0, хотя должно appartment_params_0, appartment_params_1, appartment_params_2, appartment_params_3 и т. д.
Хотя если в цикле for вывести alert('a_params_idno') он показывает что переменная прибавляется. Я так понял, что var a_params изначально берет первое значение переменной и потом его не обновляет. Как сделать так, чтобы его обновлять?
```

Comment: Только не говорите, что надо пихать весь HTML в цикл :)))

Comment: а зачем вам разные id ? если для последующего обращения, то надо просто ссылку на форму положить в массив и потом с этим работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a_params = '\
<form id="appartment_params_'+a_params_idno+'">\
<something.......>\
</form>';
```

Эта конструкция должна быть внутри цикла, перед строкой a_params_idno++;

Comment: Спасибо :) А по другому никак? Просто там много ХТМЛа и пихать его в цикл хм...

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону jsrender

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно всю разметку совать в цикл. Можно (и нужно) так:

```
var a_params_idno = 0;

var el_form= $('\
                <form id="i_will_set_it_later">\
                <something.......>\
                </form>');

for (var i=0; i<h_appf; i++){
    a_params_idno++;

    $("#appartment_layout").after(
        el_form.clone().attr('id', 'appartment_params_' + a_params_idno)
        );
    }
```

Помните: jQuery любит вас!